# Child already specified | Flutter container with headline and subheadline

Tags: flutter

When there are no results loaded on the app, there is a headline and subheadline explaining how to work the application.

However, when results are loaded into the app the Headline and subheadline disappear, and then show the `imageArray` in place of both

I am unable to group the headline and subheadline together because I am following a specific UI, and thus they require different font styles, but adding them both in a separate child seems to throw an error as the child is already specified.

What's the best way to rectify this?

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .8,
                  child: imageArray.isEmpty
                      ? Center(
                          child: Text(
                            ‘HEADLINE’,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 19,
                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            ‘SUBHEADLINE’,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : GridView.count(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          children: List.generate(imageArray.length, (index) {
                            var img = imageArray[index];
                            return Container(child: Image.file(img));
                          })))
            ]),
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout):

> All layout widgets have either of the following:
>
> - A child property if they take a single child—for example, Center or Container
> - A children property if they take a list of widgets—for example, Row, Column, ListView, or Stack.

The problem with the code is that `Center` only takes a single widget as its child. In order to display both of your `Text`, you'll need to use something such as `Column` with `children` property. This should work:

```dart
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .8,
      child: imageArray.isEmpty
          ? Column( // Use the Column here instead of Center
              children: [
                Text(
                  'TITLE',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 19,
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  ),
                ),
                Text( // Remove the `child:` property
                  'SUBTITLE',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: List.generate(
                imageArray.length,
                (index) {
                  var img = imageArray[index];
                  return Container(child: Image.file(img));
                },
              ),
            ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Center` to a `Column` this can take a `List<Widget>` called `children` as opposed to a singular `child`

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .8,
                  child: imageArray.isEmpty
                      ? Column(
                          children: [ Text(
                            ‘HEADLINE’,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 19,
                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            ‘SUBHEADLINE’,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]
                        )
                      : GridView.count(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          children: List.generate(imageArray.length, (index) {
                            var img = imageArray[index];
                            return Container(child: Image.file(img));
                          })))
            ]),
          )
        ]));
  }
```

You could also add a `Column` to the `child` of your `Center` if you would prefer that styling.

But `Column` has the built in functionality to display its children where you want with `mainAxisAlignment`